# Sometimes JQuery doesn't work with exception: " $(...).'nameFunction' is not a function " and sometimes it works

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have this problem in my website: 80% of the time the website load perfectly without any problem. 
Sometimes it gets the problem in the image below:

[image]

This is the javascript file that I call in my index:

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src="js/jquery3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="js/lightgallery.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/slick.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/lazy.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/main.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="js/picker.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://nibirumail.com/docs/scripts/nibirumail.cookie.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://web4.deskline.net/accommodationtrentino/it/qfind/script/TRN/a2befeb0-66ed-4f20-bf1a-520a5959f8cd/x?pageType=4&containerId=QF1&selAdultsSearchLine1=2&showText=true&showLink=true&lkCS=DEFAULT&width=300"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://web4.deskline.net/accommodationtrentino/it/qfind/script/TRN/a2befeb0-66ed-4f20-bf1a-520a5959f8cd/x?pageType=4&containerId=QF2&selAdultsSearchLine1=2&showText=true&showLink=true&lkCS=DEFAULT&width=300"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdnmks.suggesto.eu/vtn-hook/lib/sweWidget2.js?t=201704141221" ></script>
```

Lazy and slick object are called in main.min.js:

```
$(function() {
        $('.lazy').lazy();
    });


$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $('.slider-nav').slick({
            lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
            autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 5000,
        dots: true,
  infinite: false,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 1200,
      settings: {
          lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 900,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    }
    // You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
    // settings: "unslick"
    // instead of a settings object
  ]
});
     
});
```

It seems like JQuery is not loaded properly before other scripts are called.
Could anyone help?

Comment: where's the code where you initialize the lazy and slick object?

Comment: When you have an error like `foo.bar is not a function`, you should always look at the left side of dot too. Even if `bar` function exists, `foo` may not be what you expected. 
In this case `$('.lazy')` is probably an empty selection. There is no `.lazy` object in your DOM when this line of code is executed.

Comment: I think I found the problem: the last 2 scripts import other version of jquery. So probably the problem is a conflict between versions of jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: the scripts import different versions of jQuery at the same time. And this caused the problem.